# Using Java Code with Repast Simphony

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an already written Java code which I need to integrate with Repast Simphony.

But When I tried to set the same work space for repast Simphony as the one for my code I got this error:

> Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or
>   greater

Any suggestion?

Comment: Under `Window > Preferences`, in `Java > Compiler`, what is your "Compiler compliance level" set to for the project?

Comment: The "Compiler compliance level" is 1.7

Comment: Are you adding classes or jars from somewhere else that might be compiled from earlier than 1.5?

Comment: Yes I think so any suggestion?

Comment: Some say if you change the compliance level to 1.5, recompile, then back to 1.7 it can clear it up.  Worth a try.

Comment: Also check window->preferences->java->Installed JREs and make sure it's at least Java 7 (to match what you're compiler settings have)

Comment: I installed java 8 could this be what cause the problem

Comment: Its work fine I  change the compliance level to 1.5, recompile, then back to 1.7 and it clear it up as you said thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from the last comment on your question is correct. Follow these instructions:

- Go to Preferences -> Compilers
- You will probably see the compliance level in the version of your Java Version. Change it to the version number Eclipse is complaining about (in your case 1.5)
- It will show now errors. Then change the compliance level back to the value you had (or the one you would like)